# What happens to $-at_0t$ in the constant-acceleration equation for position?

Tags: kinematics

This is probably a silly question, but little things bug me.  If I start with the following:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}t} &= a \\
\int_{t_0}^{t} \frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}t} \mathrm{d}t &= \int_{t_0}^{t} a \ \mathrm{d}t \\
v(t) - v(t_0) &= a(t - t_0)
\end{align}$$ which means $v(t) = v(t_0) + a(t - t_0)$.

I'm good so far, but this is where it confuses me!  I can write this as:
$v(t) = v(t_0) + at - at_0$ and if I integrate this with respect to time again to get the displacement I end up with:

$$\int_{t_0}^{t} v(t)\ \mathrm{d}t = \int_{t_0}^{t} [v(t_0) + at - at_0]\ \mathrm{d}t = v(t_0)t\biggr|_{t_0}^{t} + \frac{1}{2}at^2\biggr|_{t_0}^{t} - at_0 t\biggr|_{t_0}^{t}$$
When I evaluate all of these I get:
$$x(t) - x(t_0) = v(t_0)(t - t_0) + \frac{1}{2}at^2 - \frac{1}{2}at_0^2- at_0t + at_0^2$$
With just a little bit of simplification and rearranging I get:
$$x(t) = x(t_0) + v(t_0)(t - t_0) + \frac{1}{2}a(t^2 - t_0^2) - at_0t$$
All of this matches up the usual equation
$$x(t) = x_0 + v_0(t - t_0) + \frac{1}{2}a(t^2 - t_0^2)$$
with the exception of the last term in my derivation, $-at_0t$. What should happen with this term? If $t_0$ happens to be $0$ then it all works out, but it should be universally true.

Comment: Your work is correct, and the 'usual' equation you write in the last paragraph is wrong. To see this, just factor the $a$ terms in your expression; you get $a(t-t_0)^2/2$, which is right.

Comment: @knzhou Somehow I didn't see your comment until after I posted my answer - but anyway, that's the sort of thing that should be posted as an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The discrepancy is because you got the usual equation wrong. It should be
$$x(t) = x_0 + v_0(t - t_0) + \frac{1}{2}a(t - t_0)^{\color{red}2}$$
The extraneous term you're getting accounts for the difference.

Actually, there is one more thing: you should have $\frac{1}{2}a(t^2 + t_0^2)$ instead of $\frac{1}{2}a(t^2 - t_0^2)$. That's just an algebra mistake.

Comment: Thank you both, knzhou and David.  I went back through my algebra and figured it out with your help.  I guess it's much nicer to simply integrate thinking of $(t - t_o)$ as the variable as follows: $\int_{t_o}^{t} v_o + a(t-t_o)$ to get $v_o + \frac{1}{2}a(t-t_o)^2$ and then evaluating at the lower and upper bounds, $t_o$ and $t$.